# Python pytest mocking

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

Sorry I am new to `pytest` and I am trying to mock a class but I could not make it work as expected.
Can someone help me please?

File test.py:

```
from easysnmp import Session

class testSnmp:  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
    """
    class test snmp conifg
    """

    def __init__(self, hostname="", **params):
        
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.session = Session(
                hostname=self.hostname,
                version=3,
                security_level="auth_with_privacy",
                security_username=params["snmp_username"],
                auth_protocol="SHA",
                auth_password=params["snmp_auth_pwd"],
                privacy_protocol="AES",
                privacy_password=params["snmp_priv_pwd"],
            )


    def run_snmp_check(self):
        """
        snmp run snmp method
        """
        result = {}
        result["hostname"] = self.hostname
        try:
            data = self.session.walk("1.6.6.1.2.1.1.6")
            return self.process_data(data)
        except Exception:
            result["output"] = "Login Failed"
            return result
    
    def process_data(self, data=None):
        result = {}
        result["output"] = []
        if data:
                if data[0].value == "test":
                    res = "login succeeded"
                else:
                    res = "Login Failed"
                result["hostname"] = self.hostname
                result["output"] = res
        return result
```

test file

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch, call
import testSnmp
from easysnmp import Session


@mock.patch('test.Session.walk')
@mock.patch('test.Session')
def test_run_snmp_check(mock_walk, mock_sess):
    params = {"snmp_username":"b", "snmp_auth_pwd":"c", "snmp_priv_pwd":"d"}
    snmp = testSnmp("id_device", **params)
    val = [{"id_device":"test"}]
    mock_sess_response = Mock()
    mock_sess_response.return_value = val
    #mock_sess.assert_called_with()
    resp = snmp.run_snmp_check()
    print(resp)
    
    assert resp == [{"id_device":"test"}]
```

I am trying to mock session object and walk method but it fails so trying to figure it out.

I have tried similar approach for requests module for http get and post and it works fine.

Comment: The name of the file which contains the class testSnmp is test.py? Are you sure? In the test file you `import testSnmp`..

Comment: Please include the exact error message.